# Will a nonnegative supermartingale converge to 0?

Tags: martingales

I want to know weather a non negative supermartingale converges to $0$.

I have a hunch that it shall be so, but could not prove or disprove it. Is this correct? And if so, is there a way to prove it?

Comment: Easy counterexample: Let $X_0$ be a non-negative $\mathcal F_0$-measurable random variable that isn't identically $0$.  The sequence $(X_0,X_0,...)$ is a non-negative supermartingale that doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm referring to super-martingale, not submartingale.

Comment: @user6247850 how about a strict supermartingale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this does not hold.  If $(X_n)$ is a non-negative supermartingale converging to $0$, then $Y_n := X_n+1$ is still a supermartingale and $\lim (Y_n) = \lim(X_n)+1 = 1$.